# Using decimal values in FunScript

Tags: f#, funscript

I'm getting an exception when trying to use a decimal value with FunScript. It can be reproduced simply by using:

```
Globals.window.alert(Globals.JSON.stringify(3M))
```

The exception says:

```
System.Exception was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in FunScript.dll
Additional information: Could not compile expression: Call (None, MakeDecimal,
      [Value (13), Value (0), Value (0), Value (false), Value (0uy)])
```

I suspect this is a FunScript limitation, but I just wanted to check. In that case, How could a decimal value be used in the context of FunScript code? Or How could Funscript be extended in order to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The decimal primitive is a [TODO feature](https://github.com/ZachBray/FunScript/blob/master/src/main/FunScript/PrimitiveTypes.fs#L23). I guess the best way to tackle it would be reimplementing the System.Decimal structure using the recently open sourced [.NET Framework reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs) and then add the appropiate expression replacements to the compiler like it's done for other types which do not translate directly from .NET to JavaScript like DateTime, TimeSpan, Regex, F# option or list, etc.

I guess the feature hasn't been prioritized. If you need it, can you please open an issue in the [Github page](https://github.com/ZachBray/FunScript/issues) so one of the contributors (maybe myself) can start implementing it? If you think you can do it yourself, please feel free to submit a pull request. Thanks!

Comment: I added the issue. I'll implement the feature when I have some time and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather JavaScript limitation because JavaScript has only binary floating point.
One of the solution would be creating your own type containing two integers: for integer part and fractional part